# Enlarge Stroke.hittest area

Tags: c#, silverlight

The hittest area on a stroke is tiny. Even if you make the stroke width larger, the hittest stays the same.
My idea is when you draw a stroke, draw a thick polyline beneath it. The polyline can then act as the hittest area. But the problem is, when I move the polyline around with mousecapture, how I can signal the Stroke to move around to?

All I want is to signal the mousecoordinates to the stroke when I release the polyline from mousecapture so I can redraw the stroke at the coordinates.

I've tried inheriting the classes to add a new property, ID (so each stroke+polyline has the same id), but I cannot inherit because these are sealed classes.

Any ideas?

P.S. My ultimate goal is for the user to be able to move a Stroke around with the mouse one way or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Polyline`s `Tag` property by setting it with the matching `Stroke`, and be careful that the tag is not used for anything else.

Comment: I could save a Point with mousecoordinates in the Tag property. But how do I pass these coordinates to the correct Stroke. Because the user can ofcourse draw multiple Strokes.

Comment: You could put the stroke itself in the Tag. One Polyline has one Stroke, right?

Comment: How do I go about using that stroke inside the tag though. With this piece of code I could put in the right coordinates for the stroke and redraw it at another place,                 foreach (StylusPoint p in polyLine.Tag)
                {
                    StylusPoint newpoint = new StylusPoint();
                    newpoint.X = p.X;
                    newpoint.Y = p.Y;
                    newStylusPointCollection.Add(newpoint);
                }

                Stroke newStroke = new Stroke(newStylusPointCollection);
                InkPresenterRoot.Strokes.Add(newStroke);